# Closing Excel after inactivity, even in edit mode

Tags: vba, excel, idle-timer

I'm not sure this is possible I didn't really find anything when I was searching for an answer online. I have a macro in place where it will close after 5 minutes of inactivity. Works like a charm except when the user is editing a cell the timer does not start, therefore it will not close because of this. Is there a way for excel to have a timer for how long the user is in edit mode then it will take them out of it. Once out of edit mode the macro will start the 5 minutes of inactivity. Any help is greatly appreciated!

HERE IS THE WORKBOOK MODULE

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
Me.Saved = True
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    start_Countdown
    End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    stop_Countdown
    start_Countdown
    End Sub
```

HERE IS THE STANDARD MODULE

```
Option Explicit
Public Close_Time As Date
Sub start_Countdown()
    Close_Time = Now() + TimeValue("00:05:00")
    Application.OnTime Close_Time, "close_WB"
    End Sub
Sub stop_Countdown()
    Application.OnTime Close_Time, "close_WB", , False
    End Sub
Sub close_wb()
    ThisWorkbook.Close True
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need some kind of process monitor/task terminator **outside of VBA** to do this because VBA is "locked out"  while the user is in input mode.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I am not familiar with monitor/task terminator. Can you please provide some examples of process I can use

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
Public Declare Function SetTimer Lib "user32" ( _
 ByVal HWnd As Long, _
 ByVal nIDEvent As Long, _
 ByVal uElapse As Long, _
 ByVal lpTimerFunc As Long) As Long

Public Declare Function KillTimer Lib "user32" ( _
 ByVal HWnd As Long, _
 ByVal nIDEvent As Long) As Long

Public TimerID As Long
Public TimerSeconds As Single

Sub StartTimer()
  TimerSeconds = 5*60 ' how often to "pop" the timer (5 minutes in the example).
  TimerID = SetTimer(0&, 0&, TimerSeconds * 1000&, AddressOf TimerProc)
End Sub

Sub EndTimer()
 On Error Resume Next
 KillTimer 0&, TimerID
End Sub

Sub TimerProc(ByVal HWnd As Long, ByVal uMsg As Long, _
    ByVal nIDEvent As Long, ByVal dwTimer As Long)

 ' call here whatever you want to call
End Sub
```

This always work even in edit mode, dont forget to call StartTimer to start and EndTimer before quitting...